# Text suddenly disappears in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am about to lose my mind trying to figure out what is going on. I am starting to think that there are gremlins laughing at me in my computer.

I have a site that I designed about a year ago that I still maintain. I am the only one who manages the website and I have made no changes that would warrant the problem. I always work in Chrome so any changes I make are visible to me.

I was just checking something on the website and noticed that the menu text and footer widget text are suddenly not visible. When you hover over where the menu is located, they will appear one by one. If you go into developer tools and do anything to the nav or footer, they will reappear. I tried to force them to show using display or visibility and it works in the front end using developer tools, but not once I add it to the style sheet.

I have checked every other browser and device (even using Chrome) and all is fine. I have deactivated all of my Chrome extensions and done a hard refresh. I am running the latest version of Chrome on Windows 7.

Am I losing my mind here? Can anyone else replicate the issue? If so, what seems to be the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

I guess the website would help... wow sorry, it is too late for this right now.

http://www.thehudsonhairsalon.com/

Comment: I think Chrome is having font issues as of recent update.  None of my custom fonts, including Google Web fonts render consistently.

Comment: Side note, I just noticed that even opening "inspect element" will make everything reappear.

Comment: If it's only the footer, try to add it dynamically, to see if that changes anything for debugging purposes, after page is loaded using JS/JQuery

Comment: @bozdoz I think I could deal with not rendering consistently, but not at all? Really...

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I wouldn't even know how to begin to do that

Comment: Probably a Chrome bug, I've experienced similar issues with custom fonts.

Comment: @Leah I can see the text perfectly fine in Chrome.  In my situation, it's only when I leave a tab alone for awhile and go back to it.

Comment: @Leah Don't do what hitham suggests.  Dynamically creating text for no reason other than a Chrome bug is overkill.

Comment: @Klaster_1 it would appear to only be affecting the home page though. The same font is used throughout the site and the menu is fine on every other page.

Comment: @bozdoz so you can see the menu text and middle footer widget text on the home page?

Comment: I can confirm on Chrome 33.0.1750.117, the text (dropdown menu and footer address) works fine. Everything is loaded correctly.

Comment: @JamesWong Thank you James. You just saved me a nervous breakdown. I may be able to sleep tonight.

Comment: Cheers @Leah, nice website by the way.

Comment: This is not a chat room.  Please, update your question with relevant information instead of single comments.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb Sorry but it is called being considerate and appreciative for assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to let everyone know that with the assistance of an amazing colleague of mine the issue has been found. I just checked the other person's problem via developer tools and they have the same issue and it can be resolved the same way mine was.

I don't know how this happened, but a mysterious div element found its way into my < head > section.

The culprit is as follows:

```
<div class="fit-vids-style">
­<style>               
.fluid-width-video-wrapper {
width: 100%;  position: relative; padding: 0; } 
.fluid-width-video-wrapper iframe,       
.fluid-width-video-wrapper object,        
.fluid-width-video-wrapper embed {           
position: absolute;                       
top: 0;                                   
left: 0;                                  
width: 100%;                              
height: 100%;}    </style></div>
```

I designed the site so long ago that I cannot remember how it got there, but find it weird that it only now starts creating a problem. The script was a custom.js so I am probably at fault for adding it. Not sure if where the script came from was at fault for the instruction on placement.

I have removed that div which should not have been in my meta < head > and all of the text is now behaving as it should and my responsive videos have not been affected by it's removal.

Hope this helps someone else.

**edit.**

Apparently Genesis Studio Press adds a module/plugin called Genesis
Media Project that causes the same script to load "fit-vids" which adds that div into the meta header area. To correct the problem in the theme, access your site via FTP and append that plugin folder with .old

- problem solved!

**One more note:**

> apparently this only affected PC version of Chrome.

Comment: Except mine... ? Weird. Nice find though!

Answer (score 1):

```
.clearfix:after {
/* visibility: hidden; */
```

here is the problem. don't know exactly why but try to delete this rule and check

Comment: thank you for trying, but I just removed it and it still does not display for me in Chrome 33.0.1750.117

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate the issue myself in Chrome, but there's something puzzling me about your CSS. You have the following:

```
#top-navigation {
    display: inherit !important;
}
```

I'm just wondering if something is firing to set the display to none somewhere, and that's being trickled down to the top-navigation element.

Comment: that was my attempt to try and force it to show, but it didn't work. I worked on the site recently and always use Chrome and didn't notice anything wrong (you would hope I would notice something like no menu!) So are you saying that you can see the menu when accessing the website?

Comment: Yeah, every time. I've not not seen it yet!

Comment: I am going to take a wild guess here and ask if you are on a Mac?